# MVC 5 Controller getting access to the bearer token issued by Google

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, bearer-token

I am using the default MVC5 SPA Project Template in VS 2013.  I am using the inbuilt Google authentication mechanism to authenticate my users against Google.

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication();
```

Now I need to get access to the bearer token issued by Google once the user is successfully authenticated.  How do I get this from the controller class?